# Oracle 11g compatibility with crystal report 11

Tags: oracle11g, crystal-reports

One of my application is using crystal report 11 with oracle 8i as database. Now we are planning to upgrade our database from oracle 8i to 11G. I am getting error like architecture mismatch etc. at the time of using crystal report 11 with oracle 11g. Is it possible to use oracle 11g with crystal report 11? I have to use these  crystal reports with my application which earlier was in .net framework 1.1 but now upgraded to framework 4.0

Comment: Crystal report is compatable....but question here is are you trying to change existing report or create new report

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting error like Architecture mismatch when trying to design a new report. Though I have to use oracle 11g with my existing reports

Answer (score 0):

As per the Crystal report 2011 PAM ,Oracle 11g is a supported by it.

Here is the Crystal 2011 PAM link:
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/301d4202-b3ad-3010-9b99-c819c0a18fd2?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&60258391164725

Comment: Hi Ankur, I am using crystal report 11 not 2011. At that time crystal report was a product by Business Object